# Unable to retrieve information from the Github API. JSON.parse() wont work in this code

Tags: node.js, api, github

Trying to retrieve information of any Github profile with the help of this API:

> Github API - [https://api.github.com/users/{username](https://api.github.com/users/%7Busername) of any Github account}

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
app.listen(3000 , function(){
  console.log("Server started at port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.get("/" , function(req , res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname +"/index.html" );
});
app.post("/" , function(req , res){
   const user = req.body.username;
   const url = "https://api.github.com/users/"+user ;
   https.get(url , function(response){
     response.on("data", function(data){
       const temp = JSON.parse(data);
       const bravo = temp.login;
       res.write("<p>The login of this Github ID is " + bravo + "<p>" );

      });
     });
     console.log("Post request received.");
   });
```

[Getting error in my CLI stating user agent error and unexpected token R in JSON at position 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zswbd.png)

Answer (score 0):

The target of your requests won't return in json format if there is a space or other invalid character in the uri you call.

calling with "testme" as your bravo variable rendered json but "testme please" returned html.

I think if you log data before trying to parse it as json you will find you're being served html.